# Audi.EntityFramework does not generate log

Tags: audit.net

I want to generate logs of multiple entities for just one table.

At startup I'm configuring dbcontext this way

```
         Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
          .UseEntityFramework(_ => _
        .AuditTypeMapper(t => typeof(AuditLog))
        .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((ev, entry, entity) =>
        {
            entity.AuditData = entry.ToJson();
            entity.EntityType = entry.EntityType.Name;
            entity.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
            entity.AuditUser = Environment.UserName;
            entity.TablePk = entry.PrimaryKey.First().Value.ToString();
        })
    .IgnoreMatchedProperties(true));
        }
```

I created an entity with these properties and generated it in the database

And using this Save Changes override approach

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly DbContextHelper _helper = new DbContextHelper();
    private readonly IAuditDbContext _auditContext;

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        _auditContext = new DefaultAuditContext(this);
        _helper.SetConfig(_auditContext);
    }

  public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return await _helper.SaveChangesAsync(_auditContext, () => base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken));
    }
```

But even so no log records are generated.

Is something missing from the configuration?

I'm using MySQL with EF Core

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding the synchronous `int SaveChanges()` method as shown [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#2-without-inheritance-overriding-savechanges) on the readme, and probably you are saving changes synchronously.

```cs
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    return _helper.SaveChanges(_auditContext, () => base.SaveChanges());
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using SaveChangesAsync as it's in the documentation

Comment: public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return await _helper.SaveChangesAsync(_auditContext, () => base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken));
    }

Comment: you should override both, as shown on the documentation

Comment: Yes I intend to do this, because for my test I'm just using SaveChangesAsync

Comment: You can open a new issue [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/new) and share a minimal project that reproduces the problem